# Angular2 Karma Code Coverage only showing models, modules and services

Tags: angular, karma-coverage

After searching through a bulk of the stackoverflow questions. It appears the is a fairly common problem, but no one has provided any answers for. I am unable to generate an accurate code coverage report for my Angular2 environment.

Currently, my report is only displaying results for modules, models and services. Even the ones without spec files associated.

But my Component files are excluded from the report. Including the ones with corresponding spec files.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
   var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');

   config.set({
      // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
      basePath: '',

      /*
       * Frameworks to use
       *
       * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
       */
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],

      // list of files to exclude
      exclude: [ ],

      /*
       * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
       *
       * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.ts
       */
      files: [ { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.ts', watched: false } ],

      /*
       * preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
       * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
       */
      preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.ts': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

      // Webpack Config at ./webpack.test.js
      webpack: testWebpackConfig,

      coverageReporter: {
         dir : 'coverage/',
         reporters: [
            { type: 'text-summary' },
            { type: 'json' },
            { type: 'html' }
         ]
      },

      // Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
      webpackServer: { noInfo: true },

      /*
       * test results reporter to use
       *
       * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
       * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
       */
      reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage','trx' ],

      // web server port
      port: 9876,

      // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
      colors: true,

      /*
       * level of logging
       * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
       */
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

      // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
      autoWatch: false,

      /*
       * start these browsers
       * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
       */
      browsers: [
        //'Chrome',
        //'PhantomJS'
        'IE'
      ],

      trxReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test/test-results.trx',
            shortTestName: false
        },

      /*
       * Continuous Integration mode
       * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
       */
      singleRun: true
   });

};
```

spec-bundle.ts

```
/*
 * When testing with webpack and ES6, we have to do some extra
 * things get testing to work right. Because we are gonna write test
 * in ES6 to, we have to compile those as well. That's handled in
 * karma.conf.js with the karma-webpack plugin. This is the entry
 * file for webpack test. Just like webpack will create a bundle.js
 * file for our client, when we run test, it well compile and bundle them
 * all here! Crazy huh. So we need to do some setup
 */
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('phantomjs-polyfill');

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
require('ts-helpers');

// DO NOT REORDER: Dependency order needs to be strictly followed
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');

// RxJS
require('rxjs/Rx');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

Object.assign(global, testing);

if (window.__karma__) require('./karma-require');
```

karma.require.js

```
/*
 * Ok, this is kinda crazy. We can use the the context method on
 * require that webpack created in order to tell webpack
 * what files we actually want to require or import.
 * Below, context will be an function/object with file names as keys.
 * using that regex we are saying look in ./src/app and ./test then find
 * any file that ends with spec.js and get its path. By passing in true
 * we say do this recursively
 */
var testContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

/*
 * get all the files, for each file, call the context function
 * that will require the file and load it up here. Context will
 * loop and require those spec files here
 */
function requireAll(requireContext) {
   return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

// requires and returns all modules that match
var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help, my preprocessors look like this:

```
preprocessors: {
  'dist/dev/app/!(frameworks)/**/!(*spec|*module|*routes).js': 'coverage'
},
```

Also have a look at https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#includeallsources